# Key Error when passing a variable using session in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask

I want to pass variables from a function to a class in a Flask app using `session`. This is my code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if not request.is_json:
        return jsonify({"msg": "Missing JSON in request"}), 400

    username = request.json.get('username', None)
    password = request.json.get('password', None)
    session['client_fname'] = request.json.get('Client First Name', None)
    session['client_lname'] = request.json.get('Client Last Name', None)

    ... ...

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=username)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200

class PrivateResource(Resource):
    @app.route('/protected', methods=['GET'])
    @jwt_required

    def sendData():
        return mysqldb.addUser("{}".format(session['client_fname']),"{}".format(session['client_lname']))
```

The variables I want to pass are `session['client_fname']` and `session['client_lname']`. However, when I try to trigger `sendData()` using `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/protected -H "Authorization: Bearer JWTGOESHERE"` I get:

```
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/open/PycharmProjects/FlaskMiddleware/Flask-API-Middleware-V1/authenticate.py", line 48, in sendData
    return mysqldb.addUser("{}".format(session['client_fname'],None),"{}".format(session['client_lname']))
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 377, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
  File "/Users/open/venv/FlaskMiddleware/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    return super(SecureCookieSession, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'client_fname'
```

Whats wrong with the way I'm using `session` to pass the variables? How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

If this is a cookie issue having to do with preserving the session, how could I achieve this? Now I'm creating a cookie file in `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST   -d '{"username":"user1","password":"abc123","Client First Name":"SAUR","Client Last Name":"KRIS"}' http://localhost:5000/login -c cookies.txt` and then trying `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/protected -H "Authorization: Bearer JWTGOESHERE" -b cookies.txt`. Now I'm getting `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` and I'm not sure if this is progress or just plain wrong.

Comment: Are you keeping track of the session cookie on the client side?

Comment: Presumably you previously called `login` also via curl. What are you doing to preserve your session across invocations of curl?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Correct I am. By preserving the session do you mean having a file path to a cookie file of sorts?

Comment: Yep, looks like your session is not preserving. Instead of using cURL directly, you can try using the python `requests` library by using `requests.session()`. [Look here](https://github.com/prahladyeri/tiddly/blob/master/test.py) for a sample of how I've used it in a similar situation.

Comment: What extension are you using? I'm assuming `flask_jwt_extended` because of the `create_access_token` function but I'd rather be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using `flask_jwt_extended` so you could bypass the problem by storing that data directly in the token.

```
# ...
access_token = create_access_token({
  'first_name': request.json.get('Client First Name', None),
  'last_name': request.json.get('Client Last Name', None)
})
```

And then retrieving it in the `protected` route:

```
# ...
user_adata = get_jwt_identity()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost definitely not preserving state in between your requests. If you are using postman or curl make sure to save the session id cookie. If you are using `requests` use `requests.session()`.

Comment: I've been googling how to achieve this in curl. Do I have to edit my flask code or is this done through the curl command like `curl --cookie "session=<encoded session>"`?

Comment: Use `curl --cookie-jar jar.txt . . .` like they do here: https://coderwall.com/p/iy3iqw/use-curl-to-login-to-a-site-with-cookie-sessions
ie. `curl http://url.com/login --cookie-jar cookies.txt && curl http://url.com/protected --cookie cookies.txt`

Comment: use postman it is a very nice tool for this kind of testing, I too guess it is a state issue

Answer (score 0):

Your update looks like it's likely to be progress, but perhaps the mysqldb.addUser function is returning None.

The easiest way to determine if you're making progress would be to debug with a breakpoint at the line `return mysqldb.addUser("{}".format(session['client_fname']),"{}".format(session['client_lname']))` (I usually use PyCharm for this, but most IDEs will have something for debug, or you can use pdb).  A faster but messier option, add a print statement before the call to mysqldb.addUser, and another print statement afterwards printing the return value.